# Number of Regions for a Central Hyperplane Arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

This question has likely been answered in full detail before, so any references would be greatly beneficial.  The question I have is as follows:

*Suppose we have $m$ central hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $m$ hyperplanes of dimension $n-1$ that cross through the origin.  How many regions does this arrangement split $\mathbb{R}^n$ into?*

It isn't difficult to find the answer for noncentral arrangements, this is given by Zaslavsky's Theorem.  Furthermore there is a detailed treatment of hyperplane arrangements in "An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements" at https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/sp06stanley.pdf. However, I wasn't able to find the result I am looking for.

What I could find is that if we allow the hyperplanes to be in general position, then the arrangement $A$ of $m$ hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has
\begin{equation}
r(A) = \sum_{j=0}^n {m \choose j}
\end{equation}
regions.

For the central arrangement question, the interesting case is when $m > n$.  I believe that when $m \leq n$, the number of regions is simply $2^m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this problem to have a well-defined answer, we need to assume that the origin is the only point where three or more of the $m$ planes intersect.

Assuming this, when $n\ge 1$ and $m\ge 1$, the answer is $$2\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{m-1}j.$$To derive this from the non-central answer, given $m$ central hyperplanes in $\mathbb R^n$, let $P$ be one of the planes. Define two planes $P^+$ and $P^-$ which are parallel to $P$, such that the origin is between $P^+$ and $P^-$. Every region is on one side of $P$ or the other, so it either passes through $P^+$ or $P^-$. The plane $P^+$ is $(n-1)$ dimensional, so it is divided by the other $m-1$ planes into $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{m-1}j$ regions, by the previous result. These regions of $P^+$ correspond exactly to the original regions which are on the $P^+$ side. You then multiply by $2$ to also account for the $P^-$ regions.

Comment: Yes this is what I determined as well, thanks the explanation helps a ton too!

Comment: Sorry to respond to such an old question, but I have some doubts about this present answer and I need it for my research. Firstly, it seems there is an implicit assumption that every set of at least $n$ hyperplanes *only* intersects at the origin (otherwise, you can e.g. take any arrangement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and extend it trivially to $\mathbb{R}^3$ by making all hyperplanes intersect with the entire z-axis, which would preserve the number of regions).

Comment: Secondly, suppose we work under the assumption in my comment above: In the part where you refer to "the previous result", wouldn't you need that the other $m-1$ planes are in general position when inside the $n-1$ dimensional space $P^+$? I'm not sure why that would generally hold. 

My problem currently is that somehow I seem to be able to derive your result formally from Zaslavsky's theorem for the case where $n$ is even, but not for the case where $n$ is odd (in which case I strangely obtain that the summation should go up to $n$, instead of $n-1$. Unsure if I'm correct though).

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, I was incorrect, and now have a proof that directly derives the above statement from Zaslavsky's Theorem. However, it does indeed require the assumption that the origin is the only point where there is a common intersection for all sets of n hyperplanes. Otherwise, the expression seems to only serve as an upper bound.

Comment: @Bart I’ve edited to include this missing assumption.

Comment: Many thanks! And also thank you very much for this insightful proof, it's been very helpful! (I realise I didn't say that yet.)